# What is Cognitive Intelligence?

Tags: terminology, definitions, history, academia

Similarly to the question, [What is artificial intelligence?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/7838/what-is-artificial-intelligence)

> [Cognitive Intelligence](https://luca-d3.com/data-speaks/technology-dictionary/cognitive-intelligence), as well as being a part of Artificial Intelligence, is an area that mainly covers the technology and tools that allow our apps, websites, and bots to see, hear, speak and understand the needs of the user through natural language

What is the definition of Cognitive Intelligence?

Comment: I am not sure why you ask a question if you already have an answer. In the linked article, they "define" cognitive intelligence. Now, is this the "correct" definition? I don't know, I don't really think that cognitive intelligence is a standard term anyways. Maybe a better question would have been: "Is cognitive intelligence a standard term in AI? Which papers in the context of AI have used this term?" or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term it comes from **cognitive science** - depending on the paradigm, it can have many meanings correlated with **neuroscience** as well as the brain.

Activities based on this sphere is :

- language
- learning
- thinking
- perception
- awareness
- decision making
- intelligence

---

The mentioned cognitive processes - activate the appropriate regions in the brain narrow cognitive intelligence - it's an effective response to in particular in unforeseen and uncertain situations.

However, it requires the ability to **set goals**, **learn**, **plan** and **think about your own thinking**.